# fadeToggle during long Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using fadeToggle to show a "busy" image during an ajax call. This works fine when the ajax call takes a second or two. But when the ajax call is several seconds the busy image does not show until right at the end of the ajax call - it seems to happen in all browsers.

Here is the image:

```
<img id="globalBusy" class="hide" src="/Content/Images/globalbusy-live.gif" alt="Busy" title="Busy" width="52" style="display: none;"></a>
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
$("#globalBusy").fadeToggle(200, "linear");

$.ajax({
    url: GetData(),
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestModel),
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    timeout: 60000,
    success: function (model) {
        $("#globalBusy").fadeToggle(400, "linear");
    }
})
```

I have tried refreshing the image but it didn't work. It still only displays properly when you get to the success function, so you see it only briefly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your first fadeToggle is within a jQuery document ready function `$(function() {....});`. Otherwise it will not execute as it won't find the #globalBusy image.

Example works here:

```js
/* Ignore this command - just for mocking up an ajax response */
$.mockjax({
  url: '/testajax',
  type: 'post',
  responseTime: 8000,
  responseText: {
    status: 'success',
    message: 'Working!'
  }
});

$(function() {
    $("#globalBusy").fadeToggle(200, "linear");
    $("#status").text("Loading....");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/testajax',
        type: "POST",
        data: { test: "test" },
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        timeout: 60000,
        success: function (model) {
            $("#globalBusy").fadeToggle(400, "linear");
            $("#status").text("Success....");
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.5.3/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<img id="globalBusy" class="hide" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/0.16.1/images/loader-large.gif" alt="Busy" title="Busy" width="52" style="display: none;">
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for that, the problem is that the code fragment I have given is being called from a click event of a button, so it can't really go in a document ready function. But the whole DOM should be loaded because the page is fully downloaded.

Comment: All I can tell you is that the scenario you are describing seems to be that the first fadeToggle does not work (before the ajax call) but the fadeToggle within the ajax call *does* work. The example above works every time. Would have to see more of your code to comment further.